# How to get only first x numer comma separated data from a string?

Tags: php, string

Let's say i have this string:

```
$string = "lorem, lpsum, is, simply, dummy, text, of, the, printing, and";
```

How can i get from the string only the first 4 words?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. You have to learn about explode some time, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$input = 'lorem, lpsum, is, simply, dummy, text, of, the, printing, and';
$parts = explode(', ', $input, 5);
```

Comment: do you mean that you want a string back - "lorem, ipsum, is, simply" instead of an array? In that case you could implode(", ", $parts);

Comment: this just return me the first original string:  `$input = 'lorem, lpsum, is, simply, dummy, text, of, the, printing, and';
$parts = explode(', ', $input, 5);
$comma_separated = implode(', ', $parts);
echo $comma_separated;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want them back as an array you could do this:

```
$string = "lorem, lpsum, is, simply, dummy, text, of, the, printing, and";

$arr = explode(",", $string);

$new_array = array($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3]);
```

this is a very crude example but it will work.

Matt's is better cause I totally forgot explode takes a limit param, except I think he has the string and operator reversed. see here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Ah yes, the `explode` function was the one I wanted in my answer, I couldn't think of the name.

Comment: You're right, I had the parameters backwards, thanks! `!@#$ing php...`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string on the ',' character and then take the first four of the resulting array elements. (Don't forget to trim the elements' contents though to get rid of the space).

There's probably a better way with a string charAt type function, but this was the first thing that came to mind and I've been away from PHP for *years*.